# Is it possible to rotate a window 90 degrees if it has the same length and width?

Tags: windows

I need to install an AC unit in my 36 x 36-inch single hung window, but it was installed to open horizontally instead of vertically. Are windows like this made to be installed in a single position, or can they be rotated? I wanted to check with the experts prior to ripping it out.

Answer (score 10):

### It will leak.

Windows (especially operable ones) are made to be installed in particular orientations, and a lot of that has to do with water management (flashing, sealing, etc...)

**Get a mini-split and leave the window alone** would be my advice.

Window mount air conditioners are *awful* by comparison to mini-splits.

But if you'll be removing the window, **plan on buying a new one.** Count that cost and the fuss and bother involved in replacing the window against "but awful window air conditioners are cheaper." Don't forget to count not having the use of the window, as well. And the extra power cost over time from lower efficiency, at least if you get a good mini-split.

Comment: Why will it leak?    Not disagreeing with the rest of your answer and flipping a window is crazy to me but if done right it shouldn't leak unless this is on a "wall" without any protection.    Trim should fix the "leaking".   If you are looking for the window makeup to help prevent a leak, you have more problems than the window.

Comment: The slope of the sill is designed to shed water. Turning the window 90 degrees will not have a sloped sill on the bottom.

Comment: Window mount air conditioners are *awesome* compared to "portable" ACs (especially the truly awful but nearly ubiquitous single-hose models). And they cost a fraction of the cost of installing a mini-split.

Comment: @stannius what cost of installing a mini-split? I got a 12k BTU one off Amazon & installed it myself about 6 months ago. Installation was child's play and it runs great in both cooling & heating modes.

Comment: @stannius A mini-split is not portable. Google mini-split for examples. The condenser is outside and the fan is mounted high up on the wall inside. Mini-splits are the most efficient type of air conditioner you will find.

Answer (score 6):

The glide mechanisms will be different for each type of window. Vertical types need to support/hold the entire window up whereas horizontal types do not. The weep holes and weather stripping will more than likely differ too.

I would think you could install the AC unit in a horizontal opening window. I've seen it done. Just insulate and frame from the unit up to the top of the window.

Answer (score 4):

You can purchase window units that are specifically designed for horizontally opening windows.  A search for casement window air conditioners will point you in the right direction. They are more expensive than similar standard units, but not so much so that it would be cheaper to replace the window and purchase a standard window unit. Make sure to review the installation manual of the unit before purchasing it to verify it can be installed in your window.